# Boost pool for unordered set of custom objects

Tags: c++, boost, pool, allocator

I'm having a hard time finding an example for this. My code looks like this:

```
typedef boost::unordered_set<CustomObject, boost::hash<CustomObject>, 
  CustomObjectEqual, allocator<CustomObject> > CustomObjectSet;
```

I've tried to use **fast_pool_allocator** directly but this leads to a compiler error (using **std::allocator** works). My questions are:

1. Do I need to create a custom allocator for *CustomObject*?
2. Does this increase the speed of my program?

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE]. What error? How did you try to use it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Question 1: Do I need to create a custom allocator for CustomObject?

No. It will compile without it. The allocator uses default parameters. In an example below are these the same:

```
using fast_allocator = boost::fast_pool_allocator<
    CustomObject,
    boost::default_user_allocator_new_delete,
    boost::mutex,
    32,
    0>;

using fast_allocator = boost::fast_pool_allocator<CustomObject>;
```

Example

```
#include <boost/unordered_set.hpp>
#include <boost/pool/pool.hpp>
#include <boost/pool/pool_alloc.hpp>

struct CustomObject {
    CustomObject(std::size_t value)
        : value(value)
    {
    }

    std::size_t value;
};

struct CustomObjectKeyEq {
    bool operator()(CustomObject const& l, CustomObject const& r) const 
    {
        return l.value == r.value;
    }
};

std::size_t hash_value(CustomObject const& value)
{
    return value.value;
}

int main()
{
    typedef boost::unordered_set<CustomObject,
                                 boost::hash<CustomObject>,
                                 CustomObjectKeyEq> StandardObjectSet;

    StandardObjectSet set1;
    set1.insert(10);
    set1.insert(20);
    set1.insert(30);

    using fast_allocator = boost::fast_pool_allocator<CustomObject>;
    typedef boost::unordered_set<CustomObject,
                                 boost::hash<CustomObject>,
                                 CustomObjectKeyEq,
                                 fast_allocator> CustomObjectSet;

    CustomObjectSet set2;
    set2.insert(10);
    set2.insert(20);
    set2.insert(30);

    return 0;
}
```

> Question 2: Does this increase the speed of my program?

Generally, you must measure it. It has no significant impact on example above. Inserting one million object into set1 took:

0.588423s wall, 0.570000s user + 0.020000s system = 0.590000s CPU (100.3%)

and into set2:

0.584661s wall, 0.560000s user + 0.010000s system = 0.570000s CPU (97.5%)
1000000

Comment: I can't confirm this in general. I tried with this code: https://gist.github.com/lukasm91/242641d8be60546b0b5523c984835bb1
Funnily I get 5.2ns / 4.7ns when using clang 3.9.1, and 1.2ns / 1.3ns when using gcc 6.3.1.  So when using clang, the fast_allocator is much faster on my computer, but gcc is generally way much faster.

Comment: Of course, the elapsed time will be different on Mac OS, Windows, or Linux and also different by a compiler. But the elapsed times of algorithms can be compared if it is taken on the same machine. Even your times from the same tests didn't show significant differences for this example. My point is, you must measure it because it depends on data and how is allocator used. The significant improvement would be to use some stack allocator here, be it would work very likely only for this example.